# Password reset Confirm Mail in Django2 Not giving good URL

Tags: django, passwords, reset

I am trying to make use of password_reset_confirm in built function in Django2.0 but send the sending message to email, I was getting error in my url. Please, is uidb64 not working on Django2.0

url.py

```
#path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

The e-mail

http://127.0.0.1:8000{% url "password_reset_confirm" uidb64=uidtoken=token %}

Comment: Are you using a custom template for the email? If so, please add that.

Comment: No. Built In. Auth_views